# Determine appropriate URIs and resources in REST architecture

Tags: rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm relatively new to REST architecture, I have some question about how I should implement my RESTful API for my project.

**What URIs and resources would be appropriate for:**

**1. Login and logout?**

What I guess: `POST or DELETE /api/users/auth` or `POST or DELETE /api/users/login`?

**2. Set, delete, or get user's avatar?**

What I guess: `POST or DELETE or GET /api/users/{id}/avatar`. is it correct?

**3. Verify by the sent code?**

What I guess: `POST /api/users/{id}/verification`. is it correct?

**4. Change a single or some specific properties of the user? (e.g. changing email or username)**

What I guess: `PACTH /api/users/{id}` or `PUT /api/users/{id}/email`. is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: REST doesn't care what spellings you use for resource identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Login and logout?**

For web API you have to implement [OAuth Authorization](https://oauth.net/) and then use

`POST /oauth` to get token

**2. Set, delete, or get user's avatar?**

There are no specific rules for that but humans SHOULD be able to easily read and construct URLs. So, I think it will be ok

```
POST or DELETE or GET /api/users/{id}/avatar
```

**3. Verify by the sent code?**

It's up to you.

**4. Change a single or some specific properties of the user? (e.g. changing email or username)**

Here I suggest to use `PACTH /api/users/{id}` with json body to partly update or  `PUT /api/users/{id}` to full update user. Look at [this](https://github.com/Marusyk/Simple.HttpPatch) package

You can read [Microsoft REST API Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md) to more details.